# Write to file in non-terminating program

Tags: java, file-io, io

I am having some difficulty finding a way to write to a txt file in a Java program that does not terminate. The java program is in a constant while loop that never ends, so I am never given the chance to .close() my writing streams.

I have tried using PrintWriter and a combination of File/FileWriter/BufferedWriter, and when I run my program, nothing is being written to the files because I guess the output stream is never closed.

Is there a simple method to write to a file in this situation?

Comment: Just make the program/the loop terminate. Post some code.

Comment: The program needs to be non-terminating.

Comment: @Tesla Then flush from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I wasn't aware of the flush() method in OutputStreamBuffer. What I ended up doing was just flushing the stream every time I wrote to the output stream.

Answer (score -1):

In the first itearaion of the loop create and write to the file and close it at the end of each loop iteration.

In the second interation open the file created and append the content that you want to wrtie to the same file.  just call FileWriter with true option like below.

```
  FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file,true); //true means append file.
```